# Simple concurrent Java threads--capture begin and end

Tags: java, multithreading

Am I correctly implementing these Java threads? The goal is to have ten concurrent threads who compute a sum from 1 to (upper bound 22 + i). I'm trying to identify the name and print it when running the thread, then print the result when the thread exits. Currently, I have all of the results printing at the same time in a random order and I am not sure if I am correctly getting the information when the thread begins and ends.

```
public class threads {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      final int iCopy = i;
      new Thread("" + i) {
        public void run() {
          int sum = 0;
          int upperBound = 22;
          int lowerBound = 1;
          long threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();

          for (int number = lowerBound; number <= upperBound; number++){
            sum = sum + number + iCopy;

          }
          System.out.println(threadID + " thread is running now, I and will compute the sum from 1 to " + (upperBound + iCopy) + ". The i is : " + iCopy);
          System.out.println("Thread id #" + threadID + ", the "+ sum + " is done by the thread.");
        }

      }.start();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the for-loop run from `lowerBound` to `upperBound + iCopy`, while the `sum` should just be `sum = sum + number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order the threads run in will depend entirely on the JVM being used and underlying resources.

If you have several cores (cpus) available, your code may run completely differently to a single core.

Essentially, your main loop runs to the end in a single thread, firing 10 new threads, and puts the start method in a process queue. Other processors may start running those threads. Each extra thread causes different total load, so they run slightly differently (performance wise) on each processor, meaning they run faster/slower, and end in different times.

Your code demonstrates this very well.

Answer (score 2):

I have executed your code and observed that all threads are running properly 10 in this case. Since threads are invoked in random order that is why this behavior might be seen but I an sure that all threads for running fine and executing the functionality you require.

Any how in output i saw that in for loop the value should start from 0 to 9 but here even this is random, may be because some threads are sleeping while executing and giving way to other threads.

Hope this helps
Thanks.

Comment: So the threads are running correctly and the print statements are correctly placed as well? meaning, prints that thread is running when it starts, then prints sum when it exits?

Comment: Exactly you can print the loop counter in the beginning of code block and check, Since you are printing at the thread end time you are seeing this behavior.